# как проверить строку на содержание только цифр и букв в JS (+исключить 1 букву)?

Tags: javascript, строки, проверка

как проверить строку на содержание только цифр и букв в JS (+исключить 1 букву)?

Comment: воспользуйтесь регулярным выражением https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. В примере исключаем букву f

```js
/^[a-eg-z\d]+$/.test('abcd123'); // true
/^[a-eg-z\d]+$/.test('abcdef123'); // false
```

Так же можно просто перечислить все буквы, за исключением ненужных

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте точку с запятой после первой строчки, иначе выполнение примера выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt спасибо, поправил